# How to use bouncy castle API in J2ME using eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, encryption, java-me, bouncycastle

I am trying to import and use the bouncy castle API to encrypt and decrypt a MP3 file in J2ME using Eclipse.

Even though I import cldc_sources.zip & CLDC_crypto.zip I'm getting **NoClassDeffoundError**. Has anyone had success with importing and using this API? Could you give me the steps to do that from the beginning in the Eclipse IDE?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse pulsar? Are you getting the NoClassDefFound on the device/emulator?

Comment: Are the classes / Jars in your build path?

Comment: How do you always use a bouncy castle? Jump in it! Sorry, I couldn't resist... :|

Answer (score 1):

I found it simpler and easier to just unpack the BouncyCastle source code into my source tree when working with J2ME. You can either include just the classes you want or leave it to Proguard to optimize them out.

Answer (score 0):

There's a useful looking blog post about exactly this topic here: http://tirl.org/blogs/media-lab-blog/46/

Might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem and I solved it thanks to this thread on Nokia Developer : http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?236244-moved-Series-40-Development-using-Eclipse-Pulsar-and-BouncyCastle It says that you have to change the extension of the archive by renaming it : .jar instead of .zip